# Non-exclusive job scheduling in PBS/Torque

Tags: cluster, hpc, torque, pbs

The cluster resource manager Torque typically allocates compute nodes on an exclusive basis.  However, when you have a lot of small jobs (like we do) running against multi-core compute nodes, this can result in a lot of wasted resources.  Is there any way to configure Torque to allow non-exclusive allocation of the cores on a compute node?

(These jobs are all embarrassingly parallel, so we aren't concerned about contention for the shared network resource. We can't switch schedulers as our customer's job-scripts are all in PBS/Torque.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this actually turned out to be an issue with Maui.  I'm throwing an answer here so others don't have to waste a day. :)

First: make your your Torque `nodes` file lists the nodes with np arguments, i.e. `nodename np=8`.  This will make sure the resource manager is aware of the correct number of processors.

Second, for Maui: make sure your maui.cfg file includes the line `NODEACCESSPOLICY SHARED`.  Then non-exclusive scheduling should work.